# Points of contacts of tangents of the curve $y=\sin x$

Tags: derivatives, applications

Prove that the points of contacts of tangents of the curve $y={\sin x}$ drawn from origin lie on the curve $\frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{y^2} = -1$

Comment: Welcome to math stack exchange be sure to explain how you attempted to solve the problem? Also what step are you stuck on? How did you stumble on this problem?

Comment: I came back to see someone looking into this problem, unfortunately no has posted a single comment on this.

Comment: I might as well ask if you, @Saandeep, can clarify your post. I cannot understand what you mean by two tangent lines. For example if one tangent line is $\cos(a)(x-a)+\sin(a)$ then what is the other tangent line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Points on the curve $y=\sin x$ that have tangent lines through the origin satisfy:

$$\text{slope of curve at $(x,y)$ is } \dfrac{y}{x} = \dfrac{\sin x}{x}.$$

By simple differentiation, the slope of the curve at $x$ is $\cos x$, so our points satisfy

\begin{align}
\cos x &= \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \\
\therefore\quad x &= \tan x \\
\text{or}\quad \tan^{-1} x &= x.
\end{align}

So we have

\begin{align}
y = \sin x &= \sin\left(\tan^{-1} x\right) = \dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} \\
\therefore\quad y^2 &= \dfrac{x^2}{x^2+1} = \dfrac{1}{1+1/x^2} \\
\text{Re-arranging gives, as required,}\qquad & \dfrac{1}{x^2} - \dfrac{1}{y^2} = -1.
\end{align}

Comment: That is definitely far from what the question asks for...

Comment: @vonbrand Sorry, I don't follow. Can you explain what you mean?